# Distinct selection by newest date on flat table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, distinct, max, flat-file

I have (effectivly) a flat database table "boxList" with (simplified) columns as below

`BLID, identity, editDate, notes`

BLID is auto/unique

Updates to the data are saved as a new entry.
I want to return every column based upon a **distinct** list of all **identity** for the **newest date**. All efforts have either returned "empty" or "everything" or a distinct list but selected naturally, not by MAX(editDate). (I don't have examples of my attempts to hand)

Would I be better off if I just normalised the identity column as I think that the lack of an index is the problem?

data example:

```
1,B6,2012-01-22,notes
2,C4,2012-01-24,some notes
3,B6,2012-02-01,notes updated
```

would hope to return:

```
2,C4,2012-01-24,some notes
3,B6,2012-02-01,notes updated
```

Kind regards and thanks in anticipation

aDub

Answer (score 0):

If BLID is autoincrement the newest value for a idenity is that one with the heighest BLID

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] AS t1
WHERE BLID = (SELECT MAX(BLID) from [TABLE] AS t2 where t.identity= t2.identity)
```

With this statement you get the newest date.

Comment: Doh! How foolish do I feel now - talk about wood for the trees. Thanks Marek D. :)

Comment: Your answer didn't work Marek D, when I actually go to my machine, but you defiantly put me onto the right path

Comment: Evidently I can't answer my own question just yet...

ended up with this.


SELECT boxList.* FROM boxList INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(BLID) AS BLID FROM boxList GROUP BY identity) T2 ON boxList.BLID = T2.BLID ;


Which seems to work, I assume that there is a neater way to do this.